# newsletter subscribe success email going in spam

Tags: email, newsletter, magento1.9.2.4

**newsletter subscribe success email** going  in spam to **gmail** 
How can i solve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is most probably due to settings of your domain and what reputation it has, not anything to do with Magento.

See this : https://support.google.com/a/answer/33786?hl=en-uk&hlrm=en And check if there are any other problems, which might lead to low domain reputation.

But considering the code and mail content in particular, try following these guidelines : http://www.activecampaign.com/help/improving-delivery/